# jquery addslashes to an entire form on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working with an annoyingly encrypted PHP script which doesn't let me at the source. The script outputs API results data via an HTML template file which uses variables like this:

```
%%Author%%
Amazon.com %%ListPrice%%
%%Price%%
%%ReviewLink%%
%%Description%%
```

I cannot convert this file to a php file. The encrypted php script looks for "phpzon.template.html". I want to grab the data loaded in each result i.e. %%Description%% and submit it to a php script for storage in a database. However, the content of %%Description%% for example contains html, so the data is breaking when entered into the database because of the " quotes and stuff in the data.

If it was a php file I could addslashes() to clean up the data before adding it to hidden form values, but I can't in this case. What is the jQuery way of doing this?

I tried serialize() thinking it might do this but it doesn't.

The form looks like this:

```
    <form class="uk-form" method="post" id="add-to-cart" action="index.php?option=com_entrusters&view=itemform&Itemid=351">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-margin-small-bottom" style="box-shadow:none;padding: 15px 15px 0px;">
    <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-8-10"><a href="%%Link%%" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><h4>%%Title%%</h4></a></div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10"><button type="submit" href="" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1">
              <i class="uk-icon-shopping-cart"></i>  Review & Order</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-grid" style="margin-top:0;">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10"><a href="%%Link%%" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="uk-thumbnail uk-thumbnail-mini uk-text-center"><img src="%%Image%%" alt="%%Title%%" border="0" style="height:100px" /></a></div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-3-10"> 
    <small>
            %%Author%%
            Amazon.com %%ListPrice%%
            %%Price%%
      <!-- %%YouSave%% --> 
            %%ReviewLink%%
            </small>
        <a href="%%Link%%" class="uk-button uk-button-mini uk-margin-small-bottom" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="uk-icon-external-link"></i> See on Amazon.com</a>
      %%AverageRating%%
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-5-10 "> 
                <input type="hidden" name="item" id="item" value="%%Title%%"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="itemlist" id="itemlist" value=""/>            
                <input type="hidden" name="itemurl" id="itemurl" value="%%Link%%"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="details" id="details" value="%%Description%%"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category" value="%%ProductGroup%%"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="features" id="features" value="%%Features%%"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="imageurl" id="imageurl" value="%%Image%%"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="%%Price%%"/>  



      <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100px;"><p><small>%%Description%%</small></p></div>
      <h5>%%ProductGroup%%</h5>
      <!--<h5>%%FeaturesTitle%%</h5>
      <p><small>%%Features%%</small></p>-->
     </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
<script>
jQuery( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
   jQuery( this ).serialize();
});
</script>
```

When this form is submitted the results page shows broken html as in this image:

[image: broken html]

Comment: Store it in an object with the key/value pairs you want to send to the server, then pass the object to $.param() to get a param string. I'd post an answer, but i don't quite understand what you are asking so i don't think i can answer it properly.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the problem i am getting on the results page when the form is submitted.

Comment: you can't fix this with jquery. By the time jquery can get to it, the browser has already mangled it.

Comment: Can I do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256796/strip-data-to-number-and-decimal-then-jquery-set-input-value-to-variable

Comment: yes and no. you will still have to deal with quote problems, you'd be better off using a `<script id="templatePrice" type="text/template">%%price%%</script>` and getting the .text from that

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a little?