# Strip data to number and decimal then jquery set input value to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm taking data from an encrypted php script which outputs variables as e.g. `%%Price%%`

Annoyingly those variables are not just a decimal and numeric value.

The encrypted script renders `%%Price%%` as:

```
<font color="green"><strong>Sale Price: $2,489.99</strong></font>
```

I want to strip the value of `%%Price%%` to price (number and decimal) and then place that result in a hidden form field as the value.

I have tried:

```
<form id="add-to-cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value=""/> 
    <button type="submit">  Review & Order</button> 
</form>

<script>
var price = "%%Price%%";
var newPrice = price.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
jQuery("#price").val(newPrice);
</script>
```

...but this gives an empty result

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
newPrice = parseFloat(price.substring(2, price.length - 3));
```

Comment: Actually, rereading your comment, is `price` actually, literally `"%%Price%%"`? If so, your code is trying to get a number from the word `Price` (as is my code), and thus not working.

Comment: The encrypted script replaces %%Price%% with the value returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code with a jsfiddle and it seems ok. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/CmHn6/1/. I actually replaced:

```
var price = "%%Price%%";
```

with:

```
var price = '<font color="green"><strong>Sale Price: $2,489.99</strong></font>';
```

as you said in your example. Notice that I used single quotes there. If your encrypted script does not take this into account, your line could end up like:

```
var price = "<font color="green"><strong>Sale Price: $2,489.99</strong></font>";
```

which would result in a syntax error and would not fill in your input element.
If your string never use single quotes, then you can use single quotes in your code, like in my example.
If not, you could put %%Price%% inside a hidden div, and read this value from there:

```
<div id="pricediv" display="style: none">%%Price%%</div>
<form id="add-to-cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value=""/> 
    <button type="submit">  Review & Order</button> 
</form>

<script>
var price = $("#pricediv").html();
var newPrice = price.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
jQuery("#price").val(newPrice);
</script>
```